# UnityProject FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am building an APK in Unity. I get no errors in the editor, nor at build time. However, once the APK is installed on the phone, it crashes on launch.

I have provided log output below that I can see in Android Studio when I monitor the phone while it crashes.

Can someone show me the way to fix it?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.Company.studio, PID: 28538
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /mnt/asec/com.Company.studio-1/base.apk)

at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5342)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4916)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:182)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5654)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
```

+------------------------------------------------------------------+

if you tell is duplicate same you said plz tell me about link to check it

marked as duplicate by rene, Bart, QPaysTaxes, Machavity, Paul Roub 13 hours ago

This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question "

+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: why can't Explain more plz

Answer (score -3):

Make a new project file and copy your code there and then build a fresh APK.

Comment: i do same you tell but not work

Comment: i think the app doesnt support your phone,try installing it on a higher version of android phone

Comment: Please stop badgering the OP for upvotes. You'll get the votes you deserve without asking for them.

Comment: thx - Bart for tell him